# Problem related to phase spectrum of DSB-SC signal

Tags: amplitude-modulation

[image]

[image]

I have tried to solve this question (4.2.3). I got the magnitude spectrum right but the phase spectrum wrong. I am getting the phase spectrum at \$ \frac{\pi}{4} \$ and \$ - \frac{\pi}{4} \$. However, in the solution manual, they have plotted it at  \$ \frac{\pi}{2} \$ and \$ - \frac{\pi}{2} \$.

The phase is visibly at \$ \frac{\pi}{4} \$ and \$ - \frac{\pi}{4} \$ from the coefficients \$ e^{- \frac{j\pi}{4} } \$ and \$ 
e^{ \frac{j\pi}{4} } \$ in the two terms.

I am not able to understand why am I wrong and why are they right!

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, inline equations are written different on EE.SE. Most SE's write their equations like `$ EQUATION $` but here we do it as `\$ EQUATION \$`. Secondly, if you're defining \$y(t) = m(t) c(t)\$ then \$Y(\omega) = M(\omega)  \circledast C(\omega) \neq M(\omega) C(\omega)\$ .... Basically what I'm saying is that you should double check your properties of Fourier Transforms when you multiply your time functions.

Comment: Hello, actually I have used the frequency shifting property of Fourier transform. Also \$  e^{- \frac{j\pi}{4} }  \$ and \$  e^{ \frac{j\pi}{4} }  \$ are constants. Sir, I think convolution is not needed here.